# Random connectivity error to backend with AWS ALB and Hystrix

Tags: amazon-web-services, hystrix

One of our APIs use AWS ALB and there is a backend connection handled using Netflix Hystrix. While other APIs with lower TPS works fine. This particular API with a higher TPS ~450 periodically throws backend connectivity errors. We checked the backend and everything there is working fine. Any pointers as to what could be going wrong and what can we investigate further?

Comment: Did you increase thread pool size of Hystrix command ? The default is only 10.

Comment: @yongsung.yoon Yes. We increased to 70